# 502 error caused my multiple hosts in django

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

I am trying to allow multiple hosts that are pulled from database. Its working fine locally but in production I am getting 502 error.

Here’s my production setting file

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = False


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'projectname_settings',
        'USER': '******',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "mydomain.com",
] + get_allowed_hosts(DATABASES['default'])
```

Allowed_hosts.py

```
def get_allowed_hosts(db_params):
    connection = None

    if db_params['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2':
        import psycopg2
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user=db_params['USER'],
                                      password=db_params['PASSWORD'],
                                      host=db_params['HOST'],
                                      port=db_params['PORT'],
                                      database=db_params['NAME'])
    elif db_params['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.sqlite3':
        import sqlite3
        connection = sqlite3.connect(db_params['NAME'])

    if connection is not None:
         cursor = connection.cursor()
         sites_query = cursor.execute("SELECT domain FROM django_site")
         sites_result = cursor.fetchall()
         cursor.close()
         connection.close()
```

I am thinking if there’s special nginx setting needed for this kind of setting

my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *****.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

results of `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log`

> 2020/02/16 07:16:06 [error] 32356#32356: *110 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: **.**.**.**, server: ****.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "***.***.***.***:80"